# Is there a way to use a python encoding so xmlrpc fault messages are shown on the client side with correct CR?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

On the server side of a `xmlrpc` server in python I have the following line of code within a function overwriting `SimpleXMLRPCServer._marshaled_dispatch`:

```
response = xmlrpclib.dumps(
            xmlrpclib.Fault(1, "some error\nnext line\n"),
            encoding=self.encoding, allow_none=self.allow_none)
```

to create some custom error/fault message to be show on the client side. However, this code will show something like the following on the client side

```
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: "some error\nnext line\n">
```

whereas I want to have something like

```
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: "some error
next line
">
```

i.e. where the newline character is actually 'used' and not printed.

Any ideas I can accomplish this (per server side, i.e. modification of the line just shown above, and without using a third party package.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the representation of the `Fault` object; the string message itself is contained in the `.faultString` attribute:

```
print fault.faultString
```

The `__repr__` of the Fault class otherwise represents that value using `repr()`; you cannot get around that without changing the `xmlrpclib.Fault` class itself (by replacing it's `__repr__` method or adding a `__str__` method to it).

You could monkey patch that into the class:

```
from xmlrpclib import Fault

def fault_repr(self):
    return "<Fault %s: %s>" % (self.faultCode, self.faultString)

Fault.__repr__ = fault_repr
```

Comment: Sure, but the problem is I cannot use your suggestion on the client side, except I put ALL the code in a `try..except` clause to handle the message correctly. The other way would be to overwrite some method in `xmlrpclib.ServerProxy` which handles the printing out of `xmlrpc` fault. Maybe you know which method to use?

Comment: Ok, I guess I just need to overwrite the xmlrpclib.Fault method with your suggestion on the client side (or actually only the `__repr__` method.)

Comment: @Alex: Updated after a quick check of the `xmlrpclib` code. You have to use the `faultString` value.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the `.decode('string_escape')` functionality you had in the original answer. It should be added to have a valid answer to this question.

Comment: @Alex: That depends on the faultstring value itself; your post indicates that the fault string itself is *not* escaped, otherwise it would end up with *double* escapes when printing the fault `repr()`. Decoding the string in the replacement `repr()` wouldn't do anything in that case.

Comment: The fault string is escaped, so using `self.faultString.decode('string_escape')` indeed works. But you should mention some of that in your answer, as the use of `decode('string_escape')` is crucial to the answer, I guess..

Comment: @Alex: I tested throwing a `ValueError` with newlines on the server side, the client side `fault.faultString` is *not* escaped. You do *not* need to decode that. `print fault.faultString` works without decoding. I've applied the monkeypatch in my answer, then printed the fault directly (`print fault`) as well and the newlines work just fine.